# Mysql with C++ error: undefined reference to mysql_init

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#include <my_global.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;

char *server = "127.0.0.1";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "1386";
char *database = "OurDB";

conn = mysql_init(NULL);

/* Connect to database */
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(0);
}

  return 0;
}
```

and i get linker error in codeblocks:

```
undefined reference to mysql_init
```

I used `mysql_config --libs` in linker option and `mysql_config --cflags` in compiler option.

I read somewhere i should add some libraries like libmysql.lib, but i cannot find this file on my PC (I am using Ubuntu 11.04 64bit).

Comment: libmysql.lib is for Windows. You should look for the linux/ubuntu kind.

Comment: and what should i do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting -> Compiler and debugger -> Search directories -> Linker
then **Add** and insert `/usr/lib/mysql/`

Comment: Where is "Setting"? There is a drop-down menu named "Settings." If that is what you were referring to, there is no option "Compiler and debugger" in that drop-down menu (anymore, at least). I added "/usr/lib/mysql" to Compiler > Search directories > Linker > Add, but that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is for Linux environments only:

> In "Project build options" > "Linker settings" Tab > Under "Other
>   linker options" **add -lmysqlclient**

[image]

You will also need to add **mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/include/**
in **"Search directories"** > **"Compiler"**

[image]

You will also need to add **mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/lib/**
in **"Search directories"** > **"Linker"**

[image]

For windows:

**-lmysql**

**MySQL Connector library can be found here:** http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: After trying multiple other solutions, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: you should add mysqlclient to `link libraries`, not to `other linker options`, it's just more portable. code::blocks will automatically change `-l` to whatever the compiler supports when switching compiler :p

Answer (score 4):

compile your app with the command bellow

```
gcc -o test  -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient test.c
```