# C++ mysql error - undefined reference

Tags: c++, mysql

i just include

```
#include "include/mysql.h"
```

and try to connect my mysql db

```
MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    int state;

    mysql_init(&mysql);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","root","pass","WorkerProject",0,0,0);
```

i included the files into my project. I use eclipse and linked the mysql bin, include and lib files from the preporties of project. However, i get error in these two lines:

```
mysql_init(&mysql);
        connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","root","pass","WorkerProject",0,0,0);
```

Undefined reference error. Why?

error:

```
/home/mert/workspace1/Project484/Debug/../src/main.cpp:99: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/home/mert/workspace1/Project484/Debug/../src/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
```

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: Linkage error - Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645844/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117197/). Both of them explain how to compile your project correctly.

Comment: Check how IDE invokes compiler. See the command line for details. there should be something like `-lmysqlclient`. If not, you should add it in project properties in eclipse

Comment: You need to link libmysql.

Comment: i link libmysql.lib from the ecliple's includes but still does not work